# Android use of ScrollView and ImageView outside

Tags: android, button, imageview, android-edittext, scrollview

I'm having some problems with setting some objects in a view.

I have 2 `EditText`and 2 `Button`, one below another. And at the bottom of screen I have an `ImageView` that I want to stay there without been scrolled.

**Problem**

I have an `ScrollView` with all objects inside except the `ImageView`, but the last `Button` isn't showed because image covers it.

**Edit**

My code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!-- Layout with Image set at the top of the view, outside ScrollView -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLogoFactor_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLogoFactor_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutLogoFactor_main"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextLoginUsuario"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:hint="@string/login_usuario"
            android:ems="10"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextLoginPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLoginUsuario"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/login_password"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxRecordarDatos"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLoginPassword"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/login_recordar"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
            android:onClick="setCheckBoxValue" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutEntrar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxRecordarDatos"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:weightSum="1.0">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonEntrar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="@string/login_entrar"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
                android:onClick="entrar" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Layout and Button which are not seen correctly, it is covered -->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutJugar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutEntrar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:weightSum="1.0">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonJugar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="@string/login_jugar"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
                android:onClick="jugar" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutImagenInferior_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageViewImagenInferior_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/la_electrica_de_las_empresas"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So how can I set it correctly for viewing the last `Button` when I scroll to the bottom without being covered by `ImageView`?

Comment: use linear layout instead of relative layout if you place them in a vertical line

Comment: I think your layout and your statement didn't match. You said scrollView has all objects inside it except image view. But it is not the case in your posted XML.

Comment: If I use linear layout it says me to put orientation, and I don't want to specify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by replacing the Relative Layout by a Linear Layout, as the child of your ScrollView. The Linear Layout behavior should prevent Views from overlapping.

Can you share your entire layout file and a screenshot of the problem ?

**EDIT** : as I suspected, your overlapping views issue is coming from your use of Relative Layout. Replace the main parent node Relative Layout with the following :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: I've shared my entire layout file, but I don't have enought reputation for submitting an image, sorry.

Comment: Please see my edit. I tried with this change and was able to get rid of the overlapping effect. Can you try this and report back ? :) Here's what I got : http://tinyurl.com/mlhxeas

Comment: But I wouldn't like to define vertical orientation because it's an app for mobile and tablet. What should I do?

Comment: Using vertical orientation will not prevent your app from being used in landscape mode or with tablets, and I believe it is the best option you have for the result you're trying to achieve ;) What is means is that Linear Layout will put the second child below the first one, instead of putting it on the right. That works with the screen in portrait or landscape.

Comment: One more thing : I did some tests in landscape mode and the ScrollView might contain too many elements for the last section to show correctly when on landscape on small screens. You might want to use the layout_weight trick on "linearLayoutLogoFactor_main" / "scrollViewMain" / "linearLayoutImagenInferior_main", or better yet write another layout for landscape mode. Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <ScrollView>
      <LinearLayout>
       //2 EditTexts, 2 Buttons...
      </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
      <ImageView>
      </ImageView>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this layout structure..

Comment: Else u can also use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

[image]You need to use weight attribute for this requirement. Divide layout into two parts(70/30) as i have used in the example and make top part scrollable . see attached snapshot also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7" >

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#ffff00" >

        <!-- ImageView here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The solution to your problem is to use weight attribute for this requirement. Divide layout into two parts(40:60) see example code 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="#ffff00" >

        <!-- Buttons and Edit Text here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="#ffff00" >

        <!-- ImageView here -->

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Don't want to set any orientation because it is an application for mobile and tablet.